# What is the limit size of file upload (mp4 video) when using Okhttp in Android?

Tags: android, file-upload, http-post, multipartform-data, okhttp

I am trying to upload a video file to my Ruby on Rails backend. I am using OkHttp for this.

**It is working perfectly when less MB files are uploaded. But with large files, it is not working properly and entering this block**

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
// Handle the error
Log.d(TAG, "video upload request failed" + request.body().toString() + "error = " + e.getMessage());
}
```

*Curious thing is the error when printed comes null*

**I have already tried to upload a 60 MB file using POSTMAN using same API and it worked beautifully. So no issues from server end.**]

Here is the code for reference :

```
 private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("video/mp4");

public static boolean uploadVideoOnServer(final Context mContext, final Video video) {

    final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectionPool(new ConnectionPool(0, 60000));

    String url = Constants.URL_MEMORY_UPLOAD + TJPreferences.getActiveJourneyId(mContext) + "/videos";

    try {
        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("video[video_file]", "file",
                        RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File(video.getVidLocalUrl())))
                .addFormDataPart("video[user_id]", video.getCreatedBy().getIdOnServer())
                .addFormDataPart("api_key", TJPreferences.getApiKey(mContext))
                .addFormDataPart("video[latitude]", String.valueOf(video.getPlaceTaken().getLatitude()))
                .addFormDataPart("video[longitude]", String.valueOf(video.getPlaceTaken().getLongitude()))
                .addFormDataPart("video[caption]", video.getCaption())
                .addFormDataPart("video[created_at]", String.valueOf(video.getCreatedAt()))
                .addFormDataPart("video[updated_at]", String.valueOf(video.getUpdatedAt()))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                // Handle the error
                Log.d(TAG, "video upload request failed" + request.body().toString() + "error = " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(com.squareup.okhttp.Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Handle the error

                }
                // Upload successful
                Log.d(TAG, "video upload request successful with response = " + response.body().toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Handle the error
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You might consider using Amazon's AWS library for Android, rather than a generic HTTP client.

Comment: @CommonsWare So I am not actually uploading directly to S3, its my Ruby on Rails backend which handles this.

Comment: You should try passing the exception as third argument to your `Log.d( tag, msg, exception )`, rather than just relying on the error message (which may be `null`). Then you should be able to inspect the proper stacktrace (which is likely an OOM exception).

Comment: @Abhinav I have the same issue, any luck ?